# VBA EXCEL: how do i get ouput in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is my code. I am counting the licenses and i need the total no of licenses of each type in another sheet.

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    'Initialising no of licenses to 0

    Dim transientLicense As Integer     
    transientLicense = 0    
    Dim steadyLicense As Integer    
    steadyLicense = 0    
    Dim staticLicense As Integer    
    staticLicense = 0    

    'checking conditions        

    transientLicense = Sum(CountIfs(Channeltype, "'=Radial Vibration' Or '=Acceleration' Or '=Acceleration2' Or '=Velocity' Or '=Velocity'", Keyphasor, "=Yes", ActiveInactive, "=Active"))    

    steadyLicense = Sum(CountIfs(Channeltype, "'=Radial Vibration' Or '=Acceleration' Or '=Acceleration2' Or '=Velocity' Or '=Velocity'", Keyphasor, "=No", ActiveInactive, "=Active"))    

    staticLicense = Sum(CountIfs(Channeltype, "'=Thrust Position' Or '=Temperature' Or '=Pressure'", ActiveInactive, "=Active"))     

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
    Sheet2.Visible = xlSheetVisible    

    ' changes the format of sheet 3 to text    
    'Sheet2.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"    

    Sheets("Sheet2").Activate    

    'Writes header
    Sheet2.Select    
    Range("b2").Value = "Transient Licenses"    
    Range("c2").Value = "Steady Licenses"    
    Range("d2").Value = "Static Licenses"    

    'writes new table in sheet 2    
     Columns("B:B").Select    
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 20    
        Columns("C:C").Select    
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 20    
        Columns("D:D").Select    
        Selection.ColumnWidth = 20    


End Sub
```

After clicking on the button, I want the ouput in sheet2.
Can u please let me know how to get ouput in another worksheet.
Thank u so much in advance.
:)

Comment: would you mind giving feedback to [this, related, previous question of yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41355766/vba-excel-how-to-compare-content-of-a-cell-against-specific-strings). thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

say you want to write outputs to worksheet "Results":

```
    With Worksheets.Add
        .Name = "Results"
        .Columns("B:D").ColumnWidth = 20
        .Range("B2:D2").Value = Array("Transient Licenses", "Steady Licenses", "Static Licenses")
        .Range("B3:D3").Value = Array(transientLicense, steadyLicense, staticLicense)
    End With
```

Comment: how to create new worksheet ?
what if "results" sheet is not present beforehand in the workbook?

I want the output to create a new worksheet and then show output in that worksheet.

Comment: see edited answer. ff this solved your question then you may want to mark answer as accepted, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Activate

'Writes header
Sheet2.Select
Range("b2").Value = "Transient Licenses"
Range("c2").Value = "Steady Licenses"
Range("d2").Value = "Static Licenses"
```

Avoid using `.Activate` and `.Select` wherever possible.

Best way to reform what you have done and to include the values below is:

```
'Writes header
With Sheets(2)
.Range("b2").Value = "Transient Licenses"
.Range("c2").Value = "Steady Licenses"
.Range("d2").Value = "Static Licenses"
.Columns("B:D").ColumnWidth = 20
.Range("b3").Value = transientLicense
.Range("c3").Value = steadyLicense
.Range("d3").Value = staticLicense
End With
```

As you can see, you can directly reference to value of a cell without having to select it and as you have a named Integer, you can just use that as a value directly. I hope this helps.